# NameError on Rails for many to many relation with string id field in a model

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, many-to-many

I am using Rails 4.0.0 with mysql database.

I have created 3 models, is a relationship between Movie and Genre. A movie can have many genres and a genre can be in many movies, so, it's a many to many relation, so I created another model named MovieCategory as intermediate table. The only difference is that I'm using string type for movie id (because sometimes may need an id like 'EAF7854').
Here are my migrations:

Movie:

```
class CreateMovies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :movies, {:id => false} do |t|
      t.string :id
      t.string :name
      t.integer :year
      t.timestamps
    end
    execute "ALTER TABLE movies ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);"
  end
end
```

Genre:

```
class CreateGenres < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :genres do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

MovieCategory:

```
class CreateMovieCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :movie_categories do |t|
      t.string :movie_id
      t.integer :genre_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And this are my models:

Movie:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.primary_key = 'id'
    has_many :movie_categories
    has_many :genres, through: :movie_categories
end
```

Genre:

```
class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :movie_categories
    has_many :movies, through: :movie_categories
end
```

MovieCategory:

```
class MovieCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :movies
    belongs_to :genres
end
```

So, whenever I instance a movie and try m.genres I got:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Movie::Genres
```

I don't know what's going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`belongs_to` is a one-to-one relationship. So try using

```
belongs_to :movie
belongs_to :genre
```

instead of the pluralization of those model names.

You are getting this error b/c rails interpreted the `belongs_to` as pointing to a model named `Genres`, which has not been declared.